# export: command not found

Tags: software-installation, tcsh, csh

I'm trying to install GAMESS (a computational chemistry package) on a Linux Mint machine and the config file has a `#!/bin/csh` at the beginning.

When I run `./config` the first line is `export: Command not found.` If I try to go on with the installation process I get a lot of other ''Command not found'' lines.

I have already installed `csh` and `tcsh` and this is the output of `echo $PATH`:

```
/home/chicolucio/Gabedit64:/home/chicolucio/anaconda3/bin:/home/chicolucio/bin:/home/chicolucio/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

''chicolucio'' is the user.

I tried to change the first line of the file to `#!/bin/tcsh` (the readme file cite this as an option when having problems with the interactive installation) but it didn't work. I also tried to run `dos2unix` on the file based on some links I read on internet but it also didn't work. Both attempts yields the same ''Command not found'' issues.

What else can I try? I'm kind of new on Linux.

Comment: `export` is more typical to `/bin/sh` maybe try that instead?

Comment: There are several variants of this closed source software, with decades of divergence between some of them.  Which one are you using?

Comment: @JdeBP GAMESS version September 30, 2017 R2 for 64 bit (x86_64 compatible) under Linux with gnu compilers (text from the e-mail they send me when I request the program)

Comment: @thrig I think that this could cause problems because the readme recommends csh or tcsh. Apparently because of the interactivity process (a lot of questions asked during install). But thanks, I'll try this if no csh or tcsh attempt works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that I actually have access to this software and the `config` file *is* a `csh` script (so `#!/bin/csh` is correct).  My copy of this file has a date in it saying "5 Dec 2014".  However, if your `config` file has `export` commands in it, then it is either modified or it is an updated version (with the wrong `#!`-line).

You should also investigate whether you have a `~/.cshrc` file that contains `export` commands (this would be an error). The `~/.cshrc` file for `csh` corresponds roughly to `~/.bashrc` for `bash`.

Comment: Note, though, that there are at least three variants of the software, some with divergence points that come close to pre-dating the C shell.

Comment: @Kusalananda your answer seems to be in the right way. The only line I got on the ``~/.cshrc`` is ``set path='$HOME/Gabedit64 $path'``. Gabedit is another computational chemistry software and I think that line was added by the software installation process. I rename this file with .old and clear the file. Now, with the blank ``~/.cshrc`` file, GAMESS installation works. The Gabedit seems to be working too. However, what does that line mean? Is there any chance that the Gabedit software stops working if I go on with the blank file?

Comment: @chicolucio I can't immediately see how setting the path in the `~/.cshrc` file might provoke the shell to run an `export` command.

Comment: @Kusalananda OK. I'll mark your answer as the accepted answer because it solved my installation problem. I also don't know why that line on the file cause this, I'll try to restore the file later and try again to see if the problem repeats. Thank you!

Comment: @chicolucio You don't have an alias, shell function or script called `set`, do you?

Comment: @Kusalananda No. The ``alias`` command on terminal don't show any ``set`` alias.

Comment: @Kusalananda I think that I found out what the problem was. The syntax for csh seems to be different from bash. Based on some research, I rewrote the ``~/.cshrc`` file as ``set path= ($path $HOME/Gabedit64)``. Apparently this works, no errors.